# Unit Testing-Method-ASP.NET-Help?

Tags: asp.net

Hi I have a simple method, where It takes a string as parameter **(domainname//firstname.lastname)** and takes out (**domainname//**) and returns string as just firstname.lastname.

I need to unit test for the following case.

1. check for single slash (domainname/firstname.lastname)
2. Check for empty string
3. Check for null value
4. Check wheather the string contains // or not

I wrote the following but it does not make any sense to me, coz this is completely wrong.

```
#region Checking for null value
    [TestMethod]
    public void CheckForNullValueTest()
    {
        string expected = "";
        string source = @"domainname//hari.gillala";
        string actual = Function.RemoveSlash(source);
        assert.Equal(expected, actual);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Checking for empty
    [TestMethod]
    public void CheckForEmptyValueTest()
    {
        string expected = string.empty;
        string source = @"domainname//hari.gillala";
        string actual = Function.RemoveSlash(source);
        assert.Equal(expected, actual);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Checking for singleslash
    [TestMethod]
    public void CheckForEmptyValueTest()
    {
        string expected = @"domainname/hari.gillala";
        string source = "domainname//hari.gillala";
        string actual = Function.RemoveSlash(source);
        assert.Equal(expected, actual);
    }
    #endregion


    #region Checking for Doubleslash
    [TestMethod]
    public void CheckForEmptyValueTest()
    {
        string expected = @"domainname//hari.gillala";
        string source = "domainname//hari.gillala";
        string actual = Function.RemoveSlash(source);
        assert.Equal(expected, actual);
    }
    #endregion
```

I know I am completely wrong, but some can help me to understand, how to write, what are the mistakes. thanks for the patience

Many Thanks
Hari

Comment: What does your Function.RemoveSlash(source) function look like?

Comment: it takes domainname\\hari.gillalla and gives hari.gillala

Comment: But what will it return if it is null/string.Empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your source should be a value you are performing test for:

E.g. Checking for double slash your source string should contain //.

Here's a Sample test (NUnit).

```
[Test]
public void CheckForDoubleSlashValueTest()
{
    string expected = "hari.gillala";
    string source = @"domainname//hari.gillala";
    string result = MyClass.GetString(source);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, result);
}

[Test]
public void CheckForSingleSlashValueTest()
{
    string expected = "hari.gillala";
    string source = @"domainname/hari.gillala";
    string result = MyClass.GetString(source);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, result);
}

[Test]
public void CheckForEmptyValueTest()
{
    string expected = String.Empty;
    string source = String.Empty;
    string result = MyClass.GetString(source);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, result);
}

[Test]
public void CheckForNullValueTest()
{
    string expected = String.Empty;
    string source = null;
    string result = MyClass.GetString(source);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, result);
}
```

The Class that the Test uses:

```
public static class MyClass
    {
        //Returns empty string if source you pass is null or String.Empty
        public static string GetString(string s)
        {
            string name = String.Empty;
            if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)){
                string[] names = s.Split('/');
                name = names[names.Length - 1];
            }
            return name;
        }
    }
```